# String encoding error in SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging, encoding

I am building a SQLite query as a `String` with `String.format` and passing it to `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery`. The integer parameter I'm passing at the end is hard coded to zero (I'm looking for any value greater than zero). This works normally in all my testing, but I'm getting crash reports from the field. I'm using a crash reporting website that does not give me detailed system/environment information. Here is the code that is crashing:

```
String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s > %d",
                            TableName,
                            ColumnName,
                            0);     
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

The exception being thrown is the following:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Û°: , while
compiling: SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName > Û°
```

And the last few lines in the stack trace before the crash are:

```
SQLiteCompiledSql.java:-2:in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile
SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68:in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>
SQLiteProgram.java:143:in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql
```

This looks like it must be an encoding error. However, I don't know how to tell what is the cause of this. I'm using `SQLiteOpenHelper` as a high level way to create and connect to my database, so I'm not explicitly setting an encoding. Also, the error reports are few but they've only come in on devices running ICS, so it's possible that this is something new in the defaults used in the SQLite classes in ICS.

Comment: Hey Rich, I'm just wondering... are you still getting weird encoding errors?

Answer (score 1):

You could try,

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? > ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { TableName, ColumnName, "0"};
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
```

However, I **strongly** suggest you make direct use of the `SQLiteDatabase`'s `query` method instead. Given that it protects against SQL injections, it seems likely it will also protect against the strange encoding bugs too.

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { ColumnName };
Cursor c = db.query(TableName, null, "? > 0", selectionArgs, null);
```

Comment: I'll try that and report back.  The tough thing is, this happens in the field and my reporting service doesn't tell me additional info like current locale, etc.  I think what I'll do to test this is wrap the code in a try/catch, in the catch I'll dump all of the available sys info to a custom Flurry event param so I have the data and then try your proposed solution and report back if that succeeds are also throws a the same exception.  My only thought against this is that it would make sense that both methods would end up calling into the same nativeCompile method at a certain point.

Comment: Yeah, if you are going to try one of the two, I'd definitely try making direct use of the `query` method which *should* work on any device no matter what. If I'm write about the error having something to do with `rawQuery`, it certainly wouldn't surprise me that the errors are only coming from ICS devices. A bunch of security measures were made in Android 4.0 that have caused a lot of older apps to perform correctly on pre-4.0 devices, but crash on devices running 4.0+.

Comment: For example, ICS no longer allows direct access to assets using the `file:///` scheme and will crash your app if you attempt a network access on the UI thread, both of which were allowed on Gingerbread and below. So it could be that some of the ICS apps out there are considering your raw query to be "insecure" and are somehow crashing your app as a result. That said, it does seem odd that the "error" is an encoding issue rather than an exception of some sorts.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `query` rather than `rawQuery` is a better solution, but `String.Format()` has a form that selects the locale. Not using this has bitten me in a few similar circumstances:

```
String query = String.format(Locale.US,
                             "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s > %d",
                             TableName,
                             ColumnName,
                             0);
```