# Unable to use getInt() but able to use getString() for a sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am using a cursor to access a sqlite database I have in my app.

I am having trouble using the .getInt() on my database. My database is pre-created, and I have a few cursors that perform queries to interface with the information. Several of the columns in one of the tables are set as INTEGER type. I realize that sqlite has no built in check to make sure columns are indeed INT. However, when retrieving the data, I can use the .getString() function without any issues, but calling .getInt() causes the app to crash. Below is the relevant code. If I am missing anything, please let me know, and I'll add it in.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Cursor:

```
public Cursor getSkitStats(int module, int skit) {
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM score WHERE mod="+module+" AND skit="+skit+"", null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

and I am using a simple Toast call to output the result of the query:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), scoreContent.getInt(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The variable scoreContent is the cursor.

And here is the crash output:

```
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:205)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at jp.atomicideas.ne.Summary.onCreate(Summary.java:90)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
07-08 23:53:31.726: E/AndroidRuntime(15685):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending an int to `Toast.makeText` , it assumes it is a resource id. see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context, int, int)

If you just want to print a number, use `toString()` to convert it to a String. (or Integer.toString() etc.)

Comment: Hello, you are correct. Actually to make the sure the cursor returned an int from I tried a simple mathematical operation on it. And it worked fine. It was just my mistake since as you said, Toast requires a String. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

1. "I can use the .getString() function without any issues."

   It's a *method*, not a function. :)
2. Try to avoid use of `rawQuery`... it does not protect against SQL injections and in my experience is less reliable (it's rare, but some devices exhibit odd behavior and weird errors when you attempt to do so).

   You should use the `SQLiteDatabase.query()` methods instead. For example,

   ```
   String table = "score";
   String[] proj = null;
   String selection = "mod=? AND skit=?";
   String[] selectionArgs = new String { "module", "skit" };

   myDatabase.query(table, proj, selection, selectionArgs, null);
   ```
3. You use `scoreContent.getInt(0)`

   You shouldn't hard code the integer column index *even if it is pre-created*. Use `Cursor.getColumnIndex(column_name)` to retrieve the index value *at runtime* instead.
4. You use `Toast.makeText(context, scoreContent.getInt(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

   Try converting the second argument to a `String`... something like

   ```
   ""+scoreContent.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(col_name))
   ```

Comment: +1 but there is no "hard" need to use query, he can simply use rawQuery with placeholders but also i hate when someone doesn't use parametrized statements.

Comment: Yeah, that's true... but again, it won't protect against injections by default.

Comment: 1.) method? function? doo-hicky? as long as you understand what I mean right? haha :)
2.) This I find quite interesting. Can you point me to any articles or information on rawQuery causing issues? I have tested on quite a few devices, and have not run into any problems with it yet. But if there is something to worry about, I would like to read about it.
3.) Good point, using column name seems like a much better idea.
4.) Did the trick, the problem was, Toast wants a String, an int doesn't make it happy. The int seems to work fine, I can operate on it.
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: :( Shucks, #4 was the most boring possible error haha. And I've been wary of using `rawQuery` ever since I saw this [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11197731/844882) (and there are a few other similar questions on SO about weird client-side issues as well). In several situations it seems like simply using the built in `query` method fixed the issue (or at the very least, making use of the `selectionArgs` argument when using `rawQuery`). The most important reason for using `query` instead of `rawQuery` is that it protects against SQL injections, however.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the name of all columns, and use [getColumnIndex()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the index. Then use the index to get data. Once you knew which format of the column is, you know which method you should use.

**Edited**

Your call to toast gives it the number in database. The second parameter need either an ID of string resource or a string. The value from database obviously is incorrect.

Comment: The issue is that he is trying to pass the 2nd parameter as an ineteger, but the Toast needs String.

Comment: The value from the database was fine. It was just that Toast requires a string to display. This was my mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

**scoreContent.getInt(0) it works fine** & returns an ineteger, i am assuming that at 0 index the cursor contains ineter type value.

Since the scoreContent.getInt(0) returns ineteger & you are using that value as the  **2nd argument** of Toast but the **Toast needs String** here.

Comment: Thanks very much. You are correct. Toast needs a String, this was my mistake.